# Why is ((m^e mod n)^d mod n) = (m^ed mod n) in RSA?

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic

$$RsaPrivate(RsaPublic(m)) = (m^e \bmod n)^d \bmod n = (m^e)^d \bmod n$$

$$RsaPublic(RsaPrivate(m)) = (m^d \bmod n)^e \bmod n = (m^e)^d \bmod n$$

why is this always true?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. Did you search our site? This has at least two answers on our site. Search for [RSA work](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=RSA+work)

Comment: thanks. i tried to search, but i didn't find an explanation for that statement

Comment: Because [modular arithmetic is always compatible with exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Properties)

Comment: Similar question: [_Proof for exponentiation in modular arithmetic_](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/13288/555).

Comment: the proof for exponentiation is what i needed. Thanks a lot guys!